# Inaccessable private member from singleton class

Tags: c++, singleton

I am going over a few design patterns C++, and I've come across this error.

```
class Singleton {
public:
    static Singleton* instance;
    static Singleton* getInstance() {
        if (instance == nullptr) {
            instance = new Singleton;
        }
        return instance;
    }

    int x;

private:
    Singleton() {};
};

Singleton* Singleton::instance = nullptr;


int main()
{
    Singleton foo1* = Singleton::getInstance(); // cannot access private member Singleton

}
```

I am also quite new to the material. Can I get some help in identifying what is wrong / how I can fix this? Also, I am well aware sington designs being 'anti-patterns', this is mostly for practice.

Comment: Error in declaration of `foo1`: `Singleton foo1*` => `Singleton *foo1`. After that, no more problem of compilation

Comment: `getInstance` is clearly `public`. You need to give a name to the variable by placing `*` after the type not the variable name.

Comment: Could be an interesting question to ask how come you did not get a compilation error for `Singleton foo1*`. I guess that it has something to do with the lexical analysis of the code. Perhaps the compiler has considered `*=` as the intended operation.

Comment: @barakmanos effectively, with this view, this question become interesting. What is the compilor ? In which version ?

Comment: This answer may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/3807729

Comment: @barakmanos The declaration `Singleton foo1` can only be followed by an initiliazer  (aka {..}, (...), = ...) so * or *= are already clearly a syntax error.

Comment: @Garf365 indeed, but it's only about the order of errors:  GCC immediately spots the syntax errors.  The compiler used there first spots that he can't build the Singleton beofre continuiing the parsing.

Comment: @Christophe thanks for precision. No more suspense now

Comment: @Christophe: Hence the question of why the compiler did not emit an error on this remains interesting.

Comment: @barakmanos GCC spots immediately the syntax error.  VC++ spots several errors: C2143 for the missing ";" before "*",  then he continues as if there was a statement end and finds C2248, that he can't access the private constructor (because for the moment he analyzes the `Singleton foo1` and notices he can't construct it).  I guess OP did focus on the strangest error message instead of showing all the error messages...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey @mannerofallthings,

The problem is locate in your main function where you desire was to assign the internal Singleton to a pointer to a Singleton. But you have a typo there which tells the compiler that you want something else.

```
Singleton foo* = Singleton::getInstance();
```

which should be

```
Singleton* foo = Singleton::getInstance();
```

The interesting part here is **Singleton foo*** which you confused with **Singleton* foo**. So in the first part, the one which was wrong, the compiler tries to create a Singleton instance on the **stack** (that's the first compile error, it would then complain about the following asteriks later) and due to the private constructor the compiler yells at you that it cannot access Singleton's constructor.